# android: ImageView is not displayed

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am using this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColor="#372c24" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/shape_popup">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/rateStar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/image" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but the image is not displayed, why?

Comment: Try using the property: android:src="@drawable/image"

Comment: Not a problem! Happy Coding! :) <- I threw up an answer with slightly more explanation :p

Answer (score 1):

**ImageBiew** wont display anything until it will get some source so use this

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

also modify your textview width as it is not needed as you are giving a weight.

```
          <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the property:

```
android:background=""
```

It is usually looking for something like a color, such as #FFFF0000 <- Red, and it will not fill the container with the image.

To get an image into the container with proper fitting, you need to use the property:`android:src="@drawable/..."`

With this you can also use `android:scaleType="..."`

To change different scale types of the image within the container.

Comment: There is no problem setting a `drawable` on the `background` attribute, Android just treats `background` and `src` slightly differently on `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

You should use android:src instead of android:background like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/rateStar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

EDIT:
Also you should set the android:layout_width to 0 since you are using the weight property:

```
        <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/rateStar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
```